# Why is os.path.expanduser misbehaving when the home directory has special characters?

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, internationalization, pydev

Currently, my user directory is located in "C:\Users\João", and I'm running the Python 2.7's 64-bit build under Windows 7.

Normally, the Python interpreter runs with 'ascii' as the default encoding. However, for some reason, when Eclipse runs it, the default encoding is 'utf-8'. Now, in the regular Python console, the following happens:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/filename')
'C:\\Users\\Jo\xe3o/filename'
>>> x = open(_, 'w')
>>> x.close()
>>>
```

I'll note that '\xe3' is the code for 'ã' in both Latin-1 and Windows-1252, and that everything goes fine.
However, in Eclipse,

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/filename')
'C:\\Users\\Jo\xc6o/filename'
>>> x = open(_, 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Jo\xc6o/filename'
```

Which is confusing, since '\xc6' is the character code for 'Æ', and on top of that, isn't valid UTF-8.

If you're wondering about "Permission denied", instead of "No such file or directory", a couple of programs have also written stuff to 'C:\Users\JoÆo', and I also have no idea why.

So what is the cause of, and the solution for this? Is it even programatic or do you think it's some system setting that might be wrong?

TL; DR: Home directory is correctly reported as 'C:\Users\João' in the standard Python interpreter, and as 'C:\Users\JoÆo' when the interpreter is running in Eclipse. Why?

Comment: Try ``os.path.expanduser(u'~/filename')`` (u before the string) ... I have no idea if it'll work though ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker no dice. In console, "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 11: ordinal
 not in range(128)". In Eclipse, the same, except with 'utf-8' and 0xc6, and the reason "invalid continuation byte".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Eclipse's default encoding. File Menu: Windows --> Preferences; Tree Bar: General -> Workspace; Change "Text file encoding" from Cp1252 to ISO-8859-1.

You can also change it for a specific debug configuration if you open up "Debug Configurations", go to the "Common" tab, change "Encoding".

Edit: Very weird. Performing a glob on "./J*" in a directory with a "João" directory works fine for me in Eclipse with UTF-8 and Cp1252 (the default) in 64-bit Python 2.7.2, Windows 7.

> UTF-8:
>
> ['.\Jo\xe3o']
>
> Cp1252:
>
> ['.\Jo\xe3o']